# Query a table from two recursive sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Template](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [text] NOT NULL,
    [ParentTemplateID] [bigint] NULL);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Office](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentOfficeID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Name] [text] NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TemplatePublish](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TemplateID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OfficeID] [bigint] NOT NULL);
```

Two main entities here -- Office, and Template. Much like OOP, offices and templates can inherit from a parent office or template, respectively. If a template is assigned to a parent office, it should be available to all children offices. Templates and Offices can have an infinite number of nesting.

Problem is, let's say I have the Primary Key to a particular child office, and I want to know what Templates are available to that office, including not just the templates assigned specifically to that office, but to any parent offices. Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: What do you mean "inherit"?  It sounds like you have a parent-child or hierarchical relationship rather than an "inherits" relationship.

Comment: Also what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. I suppose it's more of a parent-child relationship, but the children can also be parents.

Comment: Which is fine - but that's different from "inheritance".  Inheritance is "I have a table that holds properties for all Animals and a separate table that hold properties just for Cats.".

Comment: While irrelevant to the question, children of these templates inherit the properties of the parent template and can also override them, much like method overriding. Each child can be thought of as a struct containing a struct of the parent.

Comment: No, it's not irrelevant at all.  It sounds like you have BOTH inheritance AND a hierarchical relationship. It's POSSIBLE in SQL server but it won't be easy by any means, and there's no built-in mechanism to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a Recursive CTE (Common Table Expression.)  It's also called an Iterative CTE.  (Since it's not exactly using recursion.  But it's close enough.)  Check out [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/) explaining how to use this feature.